# Role of Const in defining EdgeInsets in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

While going through layout tutorial in flutter docs, 
I came across

`margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),`

What is the purpose of const here?
e.g.

```
  return Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Icon(icon, color: color,),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),  // <-------
      )
    ],
  );
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`const` is for compile time constant and is just an optimization.

Consts are canonicalized, no matter how often your app executes `const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0)` there will always be ever a single instance.

Just `EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0)` (outside a const context where `const` would be the default) or `new EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0)` would create a new instance every time this code is executed and also garbage collection would have to deal with it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for quick and easy explanation